# I need to load my data from database to my e-commerce index page. Admin part is perfectly fine. But I got errors in my users

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I have created two resource controllers, one for admin and another one for users.

I got the error as,

> Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException Target class
> [App\Http\Controllers\ProductsController] does not exist.

What is the problem with my code?

This is my Admin\ProductsController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Product;
use App\Category;

class ProductsController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

  
    public function index()
    {
        $arr['products'] = Product::all();
        return view('admin.products.index')->with($arr);
    }

   

  
    public function create()
    {
        return view('admin.products.create');
    }

   
    public function store(Request $request, Product $product)
    {

        if($request->prod_image_path->getClientOriginalName())
        {
            $ext =$request->prod_image_path->getClientOriginalName();
            $file = date('YmdHis').rand(1,99999).'.'.$ext;
            $request->prod_image_path->storeAs('public/admin',$file);
        }else{
            $file ='';
        }

        $product-> prod_name = $request-> prod_name;
        $product-> prod_meta_title = $request-> prod_meta_title;
        $product-> prod_description = $request-> prod_description;
        $product-> prod_category = $request-> prod_category;
        $product-> prod_price = $request-> prod_price;
        $product-> prod_discount = $request-> prod_discount;
        $product-> prod_image_path = $file;
       
        $product->save();
        return redirect()->route('admin.products.index');
       
    }

 
    public function show($id)
    {
    //    $product = Product::find($id);
    //    return view ('user.show',['product'=>$product]);
    }

   
    public function edit(Product $product)
    {
        $arr['product'] = $product;
        return view('admin.products.edit')->with($arr);

    }

  
    public function update(Request $request, Product $product)
    {
        if($request->prod_image_path->getClientOriginalName())
        {
            $ext =$request->prod_image_path->getClientOriginalName();
            $file = date('YmdHis').rand(1,99999).'.'.$ext;
            $request->prod_image_path->storeAs('public/admin',$file);
        }else{
            $file ='';
        }
        $product-> prod_name = $request-> prod_name;
        $product-> prod_meta_title = $request-> prod_meta_title;
        $product-> prod_description = $request-> prod_description;
        $product-> prod_category = $request-> prod_category;
        $product-> prod_price = $request-> prod_price;
        $product-> prod_discount = $request-> prod_discount;
        $product-> prod_image_path = $file;
        $product->save();
        return redirect()->route('admin.products.index');
    }

  
    public function destroy($id)
    {
       Product:: destroy($id);
       return redirect()->route('admin.products.index');
    }
}
```

And this is user's ProductsController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Product;

class ProdutsController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
     
    public function index()
    {
        $products = Product::get();
        return view ('index')->with(compact('products'));
      
    }

  
    public function create()
    {
     
    }

    public function store(Request $request, Product $product)
    {
       
       
    }

  
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }


  
    public function edit(Product $product)
    {
       
    }

    
    public function update(Request $request, Product $product)
    {
        
    }

   
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        
    }
}
```

This is my route.

Web.php

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/admin/index', 'ProductsController@index')->name('list_products');
Route::get('/admin', 'HomeController@test')->name('admin');
Route::resource('/admin/products', 'Admin\ProductsController', ['as'=>'admin']);
Route::resource('/index', 'ProductsController');
```

This is my index.blade.php

```
@foreach($products as $p)    
                                    <a href="../shop/product-categories-7-column-full-width.html" class="d-block py-2 text-center">
                                            <img class="img-fluid mb-1 max-width-100-sm" src="{{ asset('assets/img/300X300/img6.jpg')}}" alt="Image Description">
                                            <h6 class="font-size-14 mb-0 atext font-weight-semi-bold">{{ $p ['prod_name'] }}</h6>
                                            <h6 class="font-size-14 mb-0 atext font-weight-semi-bold">{{ $p ['prod_price'] }}</h6>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    @endforeach
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have a typo in your users *ProductController* Controller name.

Your actual Class name is: `ProdutsController` but Laravel is looking for `ProductsController`